# Responsive layout with tiles of different size; Setting proper line breaks

Tags: css, responsive-design, w3.css

I am trying to build a responsive layout with w3.css. It consists of three different types of tiles of different height and width. The layout is single column on small screens, two columns on medium and three columns on large screens (as determined by w3.css).

With a straight-forward code (https://jsfiddle.net/pwunsch/p2nL28f3/2/)...

```
<body class="w3-gray" id="home">
  <div class="w3-content w3-white" style="max-width:400px"> 
    <div class="w3-row-padding">
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="normal">1 - normal article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="short">2 - short article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="normal">3 - normal article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l8 m12 s12"><div class="special">4 - special article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="normal">5 - normal article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="short">6 - short article</div></div>    
      <div class="w3-col l8 m12 s12"><div class="special">7 - special article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="short">8 - short article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="short">9 - short article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="short">10  - short article</div></div>  
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="normal">11 - normal article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="normal">12 - normal article</div></div>
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="short">13 - short article</div></div>   
      <div class="w3-col l4 m6 s12"><div class="normal">14 - normal article</div></div>                         
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

... I run into the problem that whenever a row contains a tile that is higher than the last one in the row, the following tile is positioned in the same row, rather than in a new one (see tile 13/14 in the following example). This is actualy how I understand that `float: left` is supposed to work.

[image: example of unwanted layout]

As long as all tiles are of equal width this issue can be easily solved by setting a `clear: left;` property with the `:nth-child()` selector on every 3rd or every 2nd tile (depending on the screen size).

In this case, however, with two-column wide tiles there is no such simple counting rule. The formatting rule however is simple, whenever an tile fills the last column, the next tile should receive a `clear:left` property. However I've no idea how to implment this in CSS. JavaScript would also be fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not with CSS alone, no. If all tiles were the same width, you could use CSS columns. But in this case, if you make the fiddle smaller, the issue manifests in different places. So you're looking for a different layout engine. Look for "masonry layout" on Google.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I‘ll try

Comment: Looks like masonry is not really what I am looking for. Masonry packs tiles compactly giving up rows. The Layout I am looking for is row-based and orders tiles sequentially. Actually much more simple than masonry. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to switch from w3.css to bootstrap 4. Bootstrap 4 uses flexboxes instead of floats. Flexboxes behave as expected in the layout described above. The code is straightforward (https://jsfiddle.net/pwunsch/u35sd03u/).

```
<body>
  <div class="container" id="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="normal">1 - normal article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="short">2 - short article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="normal">3 - normal article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8"><div class="special">4 - special article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="normal">5 - normal article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="short">6 - short article</div></div>    
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-8"><div class="special">7 - special article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="short">8 - short article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="short">9 - short article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="short">10  - short article</div></div>  
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="normal">11 - normal article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="normal">12 - normal article</div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="short">13 - short article</div></div>   
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="normal">14 - normal article</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Works fine for the scenario described above. I did not find any obvious way to patch/modify w3.css to do the same.